# Oozie 4.3.0 Build Error

Tags: java, maven, hadoop, oozie

Log of bin/mkdistro.sh -DskipTests -X

```
 [INFO] Apache Oozie Core .................................. FAILURE [ 52.316 s]
    [INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Streaming ................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Pig ......................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Hive ........................ SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Hive 2 ...................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Sqoop ....................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Oozie Examples .............................. SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib Spark ....................... SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Oozie Share Lib ............................. SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Oozie Docs .................................. SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Oozie WebApp ................................ SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Oozie Tools ................................. SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Oozie MiniOozie ............................. SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Oozie Distro ................................ SKIPPED
    [INFO] Apache Oozie ZooKeeper Security Tests .............. SKIPPED
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 01:58 min
    [INFO] Finished at: 2017-08-23T15:45:13+05:30
    [INFO] Final Memory: 179M/818M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project oozie-core: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
    [ERROR] /home/azhar/Downloads/oozie-4.3.0/core/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/service/TestEventHandlerService.java:[213,46] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] variable logEntry of type LoggingEvent
    [ERROR] /home/azhar/Downloads/oozie-4.3.0/core/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/service/TestEventHandlerService.java:[214,31] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] variable logEntry of type LoggingEvent
    [ERROR] /home/azhar/Downloads/oozie-4.3.0/core/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/service/TestEventHandlerService.java:[215,81] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] variable logEntry of type LoggingEvent
    [ERROR] /home/azhar/Downloads/oozie-4.3.0/core/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/service/TestEventHandlerService.java:[221,46] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] variable logEntry of type LoggingEvent
    [ERROR] /home/azhar/Downloads/oozie-4.3.0/core/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/service/TestEventHandlerService.java:[222,31] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] variable logEntry of type LoggingEvent
    [ERROR] /home/azhar/Downloads/oozie-4.3.0/core/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/service/TestEventHandlerService.java:[231,31] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] variable logEntry of type LoggingEvent
    [ERROR] /home/azhar/Downloads/oozie-4.3.0/core/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/service/TestEventHandlerService.java:[239,31] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] variable logEntry of type LoggingEvent
    [ERROR] /home/azhar/Downloads/oozie-4.3.0/core/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/sla/TestSLACalculatorMemory.java:[817,47] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] variable firstLogEntry of type LoggingEvent
    [ERROR] /home/azhar/Downloads/oozie-4.3.0/core/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/sla/TestSLACalculatorMemory.java:[818,32] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] variable firstLogEntry of type LoggingEvent
    [ERROR] /home/azhar/Downloads/oozie-4.3.0/core/src/test/java/org/apache/oozie/sla/TestSLACalculatorMemory.java:[819,78] error: cannot find symbol
    [ERROR] -> [Help 1]
    org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project oozie-core: Compilation failure
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.CompilationFailureException: Compilation failure
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:656)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.TestCompilerMojo.execute(TestCompilerMojo.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
        ... 20 more
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] 
    [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
    [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
...

    ERROR, Oozie distro creation failed
```

I am really new to maven build and really dont understand what the issue is.
**Java Version : 1.8
Maven Version: 3.3.9
Hadoop : 2.7.4**

What can be the possible issue is really out of my understanding. I have made few changes in pom.xml to change version of hadoop, hive, pig and sqoop as

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three solutions:

1. I commented those lines, they are asserting, nothing special.
2. Is to skip tests :

   ```
   mvn clean package assembly:single -P hadoop-2 -Dmaven.test.skip=true
   ```
3. exclude those files from test-compiling from maven-surefire-plugin for that files